# How to set full size image background in UIView for All iPhone Devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using 1x,2x,3x images for full size background.

- 1X = 320x568
- 2X = 640x1136
- 3X = 1125px × 2436px -> (375pt × 812pt @3x) ->iPhoneX

I think 3X will work for iPhone 6,6s,7,8 but it is cutting from bottom.

Kindly suggest me which size of images I need to add in Images assets that support for all iPhone Devices.

Comment: Just use a large image and then the UIImageView set contentMode to AspectFill.

Comment: It's not a problem with images itself, it's a problem with content mode (aspect fit instead of aspect fill, for example) or with frame of UIImageView

Comment: 3X working for iPhoneX butt not for iPhone 6,6s,7,8. I had tried with AspectFill & AspectFit.

Comment: You can follow "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48483934/how-to-handle-iphone-screen-sizes-resolution-for-background-images/48563225#48563225"

Answer (score 0):

- iPhone 5/5S/SE: 640x1136
- iPhone 6/6s/7/8: 750x1334
- iPhone 6+/6s+/7+/8+: 1242x2208
- iPhone X: 1125x2436

Comment: Which 3 sizes I have to add in image.assets as  1x,2x,3x ?

Comment: 1x is never used anymore unless you target very old iOS versions.

Comment: But if you want to have an image fit perfectly, you need to specify it per device. You can't just use one image on all devices because they have different aspect ratios.

Comment: Should I create multiple imageSets for different devices.Is it possible to do with single imageSet?. Can you share any proper example?

Comment: I think the only way is to add them as individual images. I don't think its possible to use a single imageSet.

Answer (score 0):

The @3x image won't work here because it is used for both iPhoneX and iPhone Pluses and these have different aspect ratios.

I get the screen coordinates (sorry I can post swift code but not Obj-C), calculate the aspect ratio, then manually set one of three images with the correct aspect. Each of these images is at the pixel resolution of the largest device, so it will only be scaled down.

The 3 aspects are:

3:4 for iPads
9:16 for iPhones
9:19.5 for iPhoneX